# Cannot see my label outlet when draging file owner in Interface builder

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have this in my .h controller

```
@interface helloViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIlabel *label;

}

-(IBAction)hello:sender(id);

@end
```

I opened the corresponding .xib file and I could drag and associate the button -hello to the file owner but trying to associate the label doesn't work: it suggests me to associate -view outlet instead why ?

Comment: Have you tried `UILabel` with a capital L, instead of `UIlabel`?

Comment: Thanks, stupid error sorry I'm absolute beginner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method declaration should be:

```
-(IBAction)hello:(id)sender;
```

Also, UILabel needs a capital L

```
IBOutlet UILabel *label
```